# Android - testing inapp billing, not sure how to enable products and test with test account

Tags: android, android-billing

I have tested on my own device using the adb tool and the program seems to work ok.

I created a test account which I added inside my developer console.  But When I try to log into the developer console using my test account, Google play tries to get me to pay $25 to sign up as a developer. So I think I am doing something wrong.  How do I sign into my device with my test account?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unlikely that you're doing something wrong.  It's more likely that the feature you're asking for is a "developer only" feature, and that Google is asking you to sign up to get it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but how do I log into my device from the test account? I am using the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sign into your device with your test account, you have to do a factory data reset and then specify your test account when it boots up and asks for your account info.

A real pain in the rear when you don't have a dedicated testing device.

See [Testing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real) for details.

Comment: So after setting the factory data reset, I have to reboot the phone, right?

Comment: Yes, then it will ask you for your Google account info and that's where you put in your test account.

Comment: @Ralgha thank...but you know, on my phone, if I go to settings -> privacy, I do not see an option to do the factory data reset.  Would you know where else it could be?

Comment: On my phone (Galaxy Nexus) it's under Settings -> Backup & reset.

Comment: @Ralgha just found it - it says all apps will be erased. I can't do that :( What are my other options?

Comment: There are no other options, that's why it's a pain in the rear if you don't have a dedicated testing device. :( You'll have to either acquire another device for yourself, or use a friend's and add their normal account as a testing account for your app.

Comment: quick question....i just reset the data and now my adb tool is not able to do the usb-based apk transfer. Would you know what I need to do to enabling installation of apk via usb?

Comment: Probably one or both of allowing unknown sources for app installations and USB debugging.  On my phone the former is under `Settings -> Security` and the latter under `Settings -> Developer options`.

Comment: I got that to work. Now I finally was able to try to connect from my test account to try to buy an item, and I got "item not found" error.  ouch.